# Apply Simple Linear Regression to Multiple Data Frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, models

I have a dataset that I split into multiple data frames and need to apply simple linear regression to each of the split-out data frames. My code is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(stats)

c_data <- read_csv("D:/projects/sloper_tool/data_2013_to_2017.csv")

C_data_out <-
c_data %>%
  group_by(SAMP_SITE_NAME, STD_CON_LONG_NAME, FILTERED_FLAG) %>%
  mutate(MED_V = median(STD_VALUE_RPTD)) %>%
  mutate(MIN_V = min(STD_VALUE_RPTD)) %>%
  mutate(MAX_V = max(STD_VALUE_RPTD)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(SAMP_SITE_NAME, STD_CON_LONG_NAME, SAMP_DATE, STD_VALUE_RPTD, STD_ANAL_UNITS_RPTD, FILTERED_FLAG, LAB_QUALIFIER, MED_V, MIN_V, MAX_V) %>%
  rename(Well = SAMP_SITE_NAME, Constit = STD_CON_LONG_NAME, Date = SAMP_DATE, Value = STD_VALUE_RPTD, Unit = STD_ANAL_UNITS_RPTD, Filtered = FILTERED_FLAG, Flag = LAB_QUALIFIER, Median = MED_V, Min = MIN_V, Max = MAX_V) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date))

dfs <- split(C_data_out, with(C_data_out, interaction(Well, Constit, Filtered)), drop = TRUE)
dfs[2]
```

This splits out data frames from original inputs that look like the following:

```
$`299-E13-14.Gross alpha.N`
# A tibble: 4 x 10
    Well     Constit       Date Value  Unit Filtered  Flag Median   Min   Max
   <chr>       <chr>     <date> <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 299-E13-14 Gross alpha 2014-04-11  3.40 pCi/L        N  <NA>  2.745  1.86  3.89
2 299-E13-14 Gross alpha 2015-04-08  2.09 pCi/L        N  <NA>  2.745  1.86  3.89
3 299-E13-14 Gross alpha 2016-04-25  3.89 pCi/L        N  <NA>  2.745  1.86  3.89
4 299-E13-14 Gross alpha 2017-04-06  1.86 pCi/L        N  <NA>  2.745  1.86  3.89
```

Next I need to apply a simple linear regression model to each of the split out data frames. I tried using various permutations of the following to no avail.

```
fit <-
dfs %>%
  lm(Value ~ Date)

# Get slope by:

slope <-  fit$coefficients[[2]]
slope
```

The output from this gives:

```
fit <- 
dfs %>%
  lm(Value ~ Date, data = dfs)

Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

slope = fit$coefficients[[2]]

Error: object 'fit' not found

slope
(Intercept)          Date 
109778.966473     -5.093003
```

This appears to be being applied to the entire original dataset and not to the individual split out data frames. I would like to output the slopes of the individual data frames to a file or better yet have the slopes appended as a vector to the data frames in dfs.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't dfs a list of data frames?  You can't run a regression on a list of data frames and also piping is not designed to work on lists afaik.  Wouldn't you want to instead do the regression on each element of the list (the individual data frames)?  So e.g. lm(Value ~ Date, data = dfs[[1]] ?  Then lapply could be used.  Please make a minimal example, maybe use the iris data set and break it into speacies.

Comment: Yes it is a list. Thanks for your suggestions. I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work. I don't have your data though, so can't test.

```
# calculate the fit models per data frame
fits <- lapply( dfs, function(x) {
  lm( formula = Value ~ Date, data = x )
} )

# extract the slope from all models
slopes <- sapply( fits, function(x) x$coefficients )

# print one of the results to see it
slopes[1]
```